# adding write protection to Outlook calendars

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

In Microsoft Outlook 14.0.7194.5000 (Microsoft Office Home and Business 2010) I have imported several calendars like school vacations etc. which I only want to look into (read). Unfortunately sometimes I accidently create calendar items in those calendars instead of the default one (which is visible to others). Thus it would be helpful if I could add some write protection to these calendars or at least somehow prevent creating items there.

So I opened the preferences of such a calendar and removed the **Create items** permission.

[image: Calendar Properties]

Apparently this has no effect. I can still create items there. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have Full Access permissions on your mailbox. Full Access permissions overwrite all other settings.

Comment: Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Remove FullAccess permissions from mailbox level and set permissions per folder. You can only do that as Exchange administrator (using PowerShell / EMC).

Answer (score 0):

It could theoretically be possible using powershell as an exchange admin using `Get` or `Set-mailboxfolderpermissions -identity %primaryemailalias%:\%folder%` but that is a terrible idea in enterprise to be honest.

1. Click `File > Save Calendar` to create a backup. You can re-import the calendar if something happens.  There won't be any way to write protect your own calendar from yourself due to the mailbox folder permission structure.
2. You could create a shared mailbox or 2nd mailbox/account that contains calendars and then give your main account read-only access to them.  This can be done easily in enterprise but I don't know if that kind of sharing is possible between consumer live.com/outlook.com accounts.

I hope these ideas help :D